# loop over variables and years

Tags: loops, local, stata

I am trying to generate variables in the form `var`*year* based on a list of original variables with random variable names. For example, based on the first variable `E4252`, I'll get a new variable called `var2013`; then `var2011`, 
`var2009`, `var2007` and so on to `var1999`.

Here is what I wrote, but didn't work:

```
local myvar "E4252 E5219 E4693 E4102 E2803 E2046 E1462 E1079"

local i = 2015
foreach x of myvar {
    local i = `i' - 2
    gen var`i' = `x'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Stata that `myvar` is a local in your loop:

```
local myvar "E4252 E5219 E4693 E4102 E2803 E2046 E1462 E1079"

local i = 2015
foreach x of local myvar {
    local i = `i' - 2
    gen var`i' = `x'
}
```

Alternatively, you can refer the contents of the local directly:

```
foreach x in `myvar' {
   ...
}
```

Comment: To underline the key point, there are two distinct syntaxes `foreach` ... `in` and `foreach` ... `of` and they cannot be mixed. See `help foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives to @Dimitriy's good answer.

For a short list of names like this, you can be direct and avoid a local macro. It's just an extra level of indirection.

Why `generate` at all? It sounds as if you are adopting a better set of variable names, so `rename` saves you having the same information repeated in two sets of variables.

I'd start with the first year used, i.e. 2013 not 2015.

```
local i = 2013 
foreach x in E4252 E5219 E4693 E4102 E2803 E2046 E1462 E1079  {
    rename `x' var`i'
    local i = `i' - 2
}
```

You could just use `rename` all at once.

```
 rename (E4252 E5219 E4693 E4102 E2803 E2046 E1462 E1079) (var2013 var2011 var2009 var2007 var2005 var2003 var2001 var1999)
```

There is a simple trade-off here.

1. The last code example is simple and direct and it's easy to see at a glance what has been done.
2. But if you don't play with loops, you never learn good technique.
3. I wouldn't want to type out any (much) longer list of names, but people are going to have different thresholds here.  Also, you may have other problems of the same type, which makes mastering loop technique more important.

Comment: Yeah, I just wrote a few variables here for example. Actually I have a very long list of variables, more than thirty, to deal with, so using loop and local commands can save much work. The solution helps. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If a list of 30 variable names is "very long", what about 30,000? I fully agree that you don't want to write out even 30, but that's not a lot.